# WingIDE AppEngine breakpoints not working when launching from dev_appserver.py

Tags: python, google-app-engine, debugging, ide

I have attempted to sign up for the WingWare mailing list, but have not received approval yet, so I will post here.

I have been a WingIDE (pro) user for nearly 4 years, and it has worked really well for me. Up until recently, my project was Django-based and running on Google App Engine. Debugging and setting breakpoints worked (and continues to work for that project) perfectly.

A few days ago, I started a new project that will be running on the App Engine, but that will run using the standard dev_appserver.py  (no Django) as the entry point. This runs fine, and I can set breakpoints within the dev_appserver and the associated code, however, I cannot trigger breakpoints within my application code (even though the application runs correctly from the IDE environment). In other words, I can trigger breakpoints within the "Google" code, but within my "custom" code breakpoints are not triggered even though I can see that the code is executing correctly.

I have followed the instructions from http://www.wingware.com/doc/howtos/google-app-engine, and I have tried this even with the simplest app (helloworld.py - from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) and it does not allow me to set breakpoints in the custom files.

I am running WingIDE 5.0.0-1 on OSX Mavericks, with AppEngine SDK 1.8.6.1041.

Any idea what is happening, and how should I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may work to use old_dev_appserver.py instead of dev_appserver.py.  The new dev_appserver.py sets up the environment in a way that breaks all Python debuggers that don't implement extra GAE-specific functionality.

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested, and it does appear to get into the "custom" breakpoints now.

Comment: This answer appears relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149813/unable-to-debug-dev-appserver-in-google-app-engine